# Doctrine 2 MongoDb ODM references

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

I have a question related to Doctrine 2 MongoDB ODM in php.

So I have an **EntityA** and within **EntityA** I would like to reference **EntityB** via **EntityB**'s **ObjectId**. So in **EntityA** I have a **variableA** with the following Docblock: **@ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="EntityB", simple="true")**.

The problem is when i call the **setMethod** it sets the whole of **EntityB** into **EntityA** and not just the **objectId** which is what I would like to do.

Basically EntityA looks like this:

```
ENTITYA {
    randomFieldA,
    randomFieldB,
    EntityB ObjectId
}
```

Does anyone know if what I want is possible like how I have tried? or does someone know a better way?

Basically like this example:

```
/** @Document */
class TopCategory 
{

    /** @EmbedMany(targetDocument="SubCategory") */
    private $subCategories;

}

/** @EmbeddedDocument */
class SubCategory 
{

    /** @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Product") */
    private $product;

}


/** @Document */
class Product
{

    /** @id */
    private $id;

    /** @String */
    private $name;

}
```

Now how do i store only the id of the product and not the entire product in `subCategory->product`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how the ODM works. On the object-side, you add a whole `Product` to `SubCategory`.

Your Mongo database will only store the reference, eg (in your `Subcategory` item)

```
"product": {
    "$ref": "Product",
    "$id": ObjectId("4b0552b0f0da7d1eb6f126a1")
}
```

To create the relationship, you simply set your `Product` into the `SubCategory`, eg

```
// $product is a persisted Product object
$subcategory->setProduct($product);
```

To get the `Product` ID from `SubCategory`, you just use

```
$productId = $subcategory->getProduct()->getId();
```

(assuming you have the appropriate *setter* and *getter* methods defined)

---

You use *references* when you want to create a relationship to a stand-alone document. This is particularly true where you may want to link to one document (like your *Product*) from many other documents (like your *SubCategories*).

Embedded documents are used when you only want that document as part of its parent.

Comment: So like in my Product example. SubCategory->product only contains the ID of the Product?

Comment: Also when would you use Reference and when would you use Embed?

Comment: @user1154863 No, the `product` property of `SubCategory` would contain an object of type `Product`. I've updated my answer with more information